# How to generate random Directed Connected (Planar) graphs?

Tags: graphs-and-networks

I need to create all possible connected and directed graphs with N vertices. The graphs are Planar and labelled with vertices  1 to N. Although the graphs are unweighted, the graphs are non simple since they are directed. Isomorphic graphs must be discarded. We must consider the following characteristics:

1. Vertex 1 has one connected edge (degree=1), and direction: from vertex1 to vertex2
2. Vertex N has one connected edge (degree=1), and direction: from vertex(N-1) to vertexN
3. All other vertices must have degree=3 (three conected edges), with at least one edge entering and one edge going out of the vertex.
4. Vertex1 always connect to vertex2. Direction: vertex1-->vertex2
5. Vertex(N-1) always connect to vertexN. Direction: vertex(N-1)-->vertexN

How can I do it efficiently?

And How can I save each graph separately for individual use afterwards?

Comment: Welcome to *Mathematica*.SE! Is the question about *Mathematica*, the software or should we move the question over to [Math.SE]?

Comment: What have you tried?

Comment: Do you need all possible directed graphs, or some random graphs?

Comment: Are only simple graphs allowed? That is, in this case no multiple edges between two vertices?

Comment: Please clarify the question. The title says random graphs, but there is no mention of this in the question. The title mentions planar, the body doesn't. Are the graphs labelled or not? Does vertex 1 always connect to vertex 2 (and not vertex 3), or do you just mean that it's out-degree is 1?  Voting to close the question until it is made to be clear and unambiguous.

Comment: Answer 2 dos not work for n=4 ..

Comment: @Szabolcs I think this is an interesting question to tackle, but it definitely requires more stringent definition of the problem at hand. Are non-simple graphs allowed? Is uniform sampling required, and how about graph isomorphisms in that case? Is enumerating all graphs a good alternative as a solution? (Well, that wouldn't probably work for more than the smallest graphs...)

Comment: I vote for leaving it closed, as the questions raised by Szabolcs are not addressed. It makes a huge difference, if it is required, that the graph is planar.

Comment: @Johu It definitely does make a difference. I have been thinking whole day how to reason about planarity using Boolean satisfiability without blowing up the problem entirely!

Comment: @J.R.Descardeci I see that you edited the question, but none of the issues we raised were addressed. It cannot be reopened this way.

Comment: Approximately how big is N?

Comment: Please edit the title to make it consistent with the post body. It is now clear enough that I can write an answer. Next time please ensure that the question is precisely formulated on the first try.

Comment: Until it gets reopened, here's a start: 1. Use the `geng` tool from nauty to generate cubic graphs (`-d3D3` option) on $N-2$ vertices. Mathematica can imports its output format (Graph6). 2. Cut one edge and stich on the first and last vertex on the edge-stubs that were created this way. Consider all possibilities. 3. Verify if the result is `PlanarGraphQ` 4. Order the $N-2$ vertices in all $(N-2)!$ ways, keeping the first and last vertices in their original positions. Orient the edges to create a directed acylic graph based on each ordering (`DirectedGraph[..., "Acyclic"]`).

Comment: 5. This way, you'll have *lots* of graphs. Filter isomorphic duplicates with `DeleteDuplicatesBy` according to `CanonicalGraph`.  This method will work, but only if you have few vertices (say, not much more than 10).

Comment: Actually, step 4. above is incorrect. We'd need some other way to create all orientations that satisfy your criterion.

Comment: Some more clarification would actually be useful.  If isomorphic duplicates must be discarded that means that you do *not* want labelled graphs (but this is clear enough). If we have labelled graphs, then `1->2` is distinct from `2->1` (even though they are isomorphic).

Comment: I am still confused about this statement: "the graphs are non simple since they are directed". Non-simple does not mean directed. It means that there may be more than one edge between the same vertices, or that there may be an edge connecting a vertex with itself (self-loop). Do you allow each of these?  If you allow self-loops, how do you cound the degree of its vertex? Is it 1 or 2?  (Clearly both the in- and out-degrees are 1). Finally, it seems clear that [this graph](http://i.stack.imgur.com/RkFSE.png) is allowed. What about [this one](http://i.stack.imgur.com/cggqo.png)?

Comment: While these might seem like small details, they could make an already hard problem much harder. Given the difficulty of this task, could you state if listing *all* valid graphics is critical? Or would an approach that lists only *some* of them be also of some use?

Answer (score 5):

For the easier case of generating a random undirected planar graph with given degree distribution, you can generate a random graph with the desired degree distribution using [`DegreeGraphDistribution`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/DegreeGraphDistribution.html) until you get a [`PlanarGraph`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/PlanarGraph.html):

```
rpg[n_] := Module[{g}, Quiet[While[Not @ PlanarGraphQ[
   g = RandomGraph[DegreeGraphDistribution[Flatten[{1, ConstantArray[3, n - 2], 1}], 
     SelfLoops -> False]]]]; 
  PlanarGraph[Range @ n, EdgeList @ g]]]
```

**Examples:**

```
n = 6;
Grid[Partition[Table[With[{g = rpg[n] }, SetProperty[g, {ImageSize -> 300, 
  GraphStyle -> "VintageDiagram",  EdgeShapeFunction -> "CurvedArc", 
  PlotLabel -> VertexDegree[g]} ]], 6], 3]]
```

[image]

```
n = 8;
```

[image]

```
n = 10;
```

[image]

```
n = 12;
```

[image]

**TODO:** Process the `EdgeList` or the `AdjacencyMatrix` of `rpg[n]` to get the desired configuration of edge directions.

Answer (score 3):

It won't necessarily have all the properties you desire, but this will get you a directed connected planar graph:

```
pts = RandomReal[{-1, 1}, {25, 2}];
myR = DelaunayMesh[pts];
```

Extract the point adjacencies:

```
   mycells =( MeshCells[myR, 1] /. Line[n_] -> n)
```

Get connection rules:

```
therules = (Rule[#[[1]] , #[[2]]] & /@ mycells)
```

Create the graph

```
Graph[therules]
```

[image]

Confirm:

```
PlanarGraphQ[%]
```

(* True *)